# Grails GSP outer templates with inner content?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, gsp

Is there a way in Grails GSP to replace the following

```
<tmpl:/templates/header />
<!-- tmpl namespace call is equivalent to <g:render template="/templates/header" /> -->    

<!-- definition of inner content -->

<tmpl:/templates/footer />
```

With an outer template? Essentially, a way to import the wrapping outer template,

```
<outertemplate:templatename>
<!-- header will be rendered from outer template -->

<!-- definition of inner content -->

<!-- footer will be rendered from outer template -->
</outertemplate:templatename>
```

and the definition of the outer template being something along the lines of

```
<!-- definition of header content -->

<!-- placeholder or attr for inner content -->

<!-- definition of footer content -->
```

Encapsulating the wrapping content in a single template versus two. IIRC there was a way to do this under JSF but I can't find an equivalent under GSP.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Templates can render templates.

Comment: Can you elaborate more your question?

Comment: @James McMahon, your question is too specific to the apparent refactoring that you're trying to make. We would need to know what the tmpl tagLib does first.

Comment: I've tried to make the question clearer, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so what I was looking for was [Grails' SiteMesh layout support](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#layouts), which allows me to define commonly used view markup in a more eloquent manner then templates.

So the header and footer content can be placed inside a layout

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><g:layoutTitle/></title>
        <g:layoutHead />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- HEADER CONTENT DEFINED HERE (or for stuff in head in the head above -->
        <g:layoutBody />
        <!-- FOOTER CONTENT DEFINED HERE -->
    </body>
</html>
```

And then use the layout,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>An Example Page</title>
        <meta name="layout" content="main" />
    </head>
    <body>This is my content!</body>
</html>
```

Which I think is much cleaner then header and footer templates.

[You can also nest layouts.](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/03/grails-goodness-applying-layouts-in.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can create something like this using a tag library.

```
class SimpleTagLib {
    def emoticon = { attrs, body ->
       out << body() << (attrs.happy == 'true' ? " :-)" : " :-(")
    }
}
```

This defines a tag `emoticon` that can be used in gsp like this:

```
<g:emoticon happy="true">Hi John</g:emoticon>
```

`body()` is used to render the tag body content.

(The example is copied from the offical [grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#6.3%20Tag%20Libraries))

Comment: Ah I support I could make a tag library to render the other template and pass in the inner content, seems a little heavy but I am still figuring out all this grails / gsp stuff